# How to exclude a variable from being required in a function?

Tags: php, function

How to exclude a variable from being required in a function?

IE:

```
function foo($name,$address,$pizza_preference,$date)
{
if(!$pizza_preference)
{
return array($name,$address,$date);    
}
else
{
return array($name,$address,$pizza_preference,$date);
}
}
```

When calling this function how would I set it up so `$pizza_preference` is not required, but optional? So that if you only entered 3 arguments in the function it omits `$pizza_preference`, or would I have to make it so when you enter 0 it just doesn't return it?

Comment: @blake: PHP doesn't let you skip arguments. since $date has no arguments, you'll get a missing argument error if you leave pizza_preference blank

Comment: @MarcB You are correct, meant to put it at the end before submitting. Broken hand == slower to change things on typing than in head. One handed typing sucks, too.

Comment: The issue I have with the answers here is, what if I have 2 or more null values at the end, but I want to access the last one less then the first, yet I need to access it when not accessing the other? IE `$pizza_preference=null,$date=null`

Comment: Why can't you handle the data being returned, even if it's null?

Comment: Ah never mind, I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a default value for it. Then you can use that function without passing a value:

```
function foo($name,$address,$date,$pizza_preference=null)
{
    if(!$pizza_preference)
    {
        return array($name,$address,$date);    
    }
    else
    {
        return array($name,$address,$pizza_preference,$date);
    }
}
```

Usually you put variables that have default values at the end of the parameters list so you don't have to include blank parameters when calling the function.

See [Default argument values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) on the PHP website for more.

**UPDATE**

If you're going to have multiple parameters with default values and want to be able to skip them individually you can pass an array as the only parameter and read the values from there:

```
function foo(array $parameters)
{
    if(!$parameters['pizza_preference'])
    {
        return array($parameters['name'],$parameters['address'],$parameters['date']);    
    }
    else
    {
        return array($parameters['name'],$parameters['address'],$parameters['date'],$parameters['pizza_preference']);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Until PHP supports named parameters this is a drawback of the language. Your only other options is to pass your parameters as an array.

Comment: By named parameter your talking about using an associative array right?

Comment: Actually no. [Here's how python](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html) does it (also known as named arguments).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend (and I always do) to pass arguments as Object..

```
function foo($params)
{
  if(!$params->pizza_preference)
  {
    return array($pizza_preference->name,$pizza_preference->address,$pizza_preference->date);    
  }
  else
  {
    return array($pizza_preference->name,$pizza_preference->pizza_preference->address,$pizza_preference,$pizza_preference->date);
  }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$p1 = new stdClass;
$p1->name = 'same name';
$p1->address ='same address';
$p1->pizza_preference = '1';
$p1->date = '26-04-2012';

$p2 = new stdClass;
$p2->name = 'same name';
$p2->address ='same address';
$p2->date = '26-04-2012';

foo($p1); //will return the first array
foo($p2); //will return the second array
```

Comment: This seems not to work for me for some reason (calling foo($p1);), If I'm using my own class `people_handler` how would I call foo from within it and print the information I created? $p1->foo($p1)?

Answer (score 0):

Well youll need to change the signature... anything not required should go last:

```
function foo($name, $address, $date, $pizza_preference = null) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set default values in the function declaration:

```
function foo($name,$address,$date,$pizza_preference=null)
{
   if($pizza_preference === null)
   {
      return array($name,$address,$date);    
   }
   else
   {
      return array($name,$address,$pizza_preference,$date);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you can use an associative array as a single argument, and then just check it inside the function like this:

```
function foo($args) {
    $name = (!empty($args['name']) ? $args['name'] : NULL);
    $address = (!empty($args['address']) ? $args['address'] : NULL);
    $pizza_preference = (!empty($args['pizza_preference']) ? $args['pizza_preference'] : NULL);
    $date = (!empty($args['date']) ? $args['date'] : NULL);
}
```